# How to make web application to use latest .net framework?

Tags: .net, frameworks

I am running a web application on local host on Windows 7. I want my application to use .Net version 3.5 but it is using version 2.0.50727.4971. I confirmed it through code by using command "Environment.Version". I checked the C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework folder there are also folder of version 3.0 and version 3.5. I also configured the my project properties in Visual Studio 2008 to use the version 3.5. Please tell me why my application is using version 2.0.50727.4971? How can i change it to use the latest version 3.5?

Comment: 'latest version 3.5'? The latest version (stable) is 4.0 or (beta) 4.5.

Comment: [Specify a .NET Framework Version for an Application Pool (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754523%28v=ws.10%29)

Answer (score 0):

In your project **settings** you can change the target framework to .NET 4.0(or whichever is the latest available on your machine)

> On the Project menu, click ProjectName Properties.
>
> Click the Compile tab.
>
> Click Advanced Compile Options.
>
> In the Target Framework (all configurations) list, select either .NET
>   Framework 2.0, .NET Framework 3.0, or .NET Framework 3.5.

See full article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772098%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

For **IIS7**, you need to change the application or application pool settings.

1. [Specify a .NET Framework Version for an Application Pool (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754523%28v=ws.10%29)
2. [How to set an IIS Application or AppPool to use ASP.NET 3.5 rather than 2.0](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToSetAnIISApplicationOrAppPoolToUseASPNET35RatherThan20.aspx)

Comment: Oh it figured out that i was actually using 3.5 but as it is built on 2.0 that's why it shows 2.0.50727.4971. v3.5 is built upon v2 so you are using the correct version even though it says v2.
v3.5 is not a separate version like v4 but more or less an update to v2.
The only time you will need to change from v2 would be if you upgraded the application to v4.

This might help clear things up:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049.aspx